# type inference in argument list in combination with setter not working

Tags: scala, functional-programming, anonymous-function, type-inference

Let's imagine the following items in scope:

```
object Thing { 
  var data: Box[String] = Empty
}

def perform[T](setter: Box[T] => Unit) {
  // doesn't matter
}
```

The following fails to compile:

```
perform(Thing.data = _)
```

The error message is:

```
<console>:12: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => Thing.data = x$1)
              perform(Thing.data = _)
                                   ^
<console>:12: warning: a type was inferred to be `Any`; this may indicate a programming error.
              perform(Thing.data = _)
                                 ^
```

While the following compiles:

```
perform(Thing.data_=)
```

I have since surpassed this issue by creating a better abstraction, but my curiosity still remains.

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: `T` comes out of nowhere. Is it supposed to be a type parameter to  method `process`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's expand out what you're doing in the first example:

```
Thing.data = _
```

is shorthand for defining an anonymous function, which looks like:

```
def anon[T](x: Box[T]) {
  Thing.data = x
}
```

So when you call

```
perform(Thing.data = _)
```

it's the same as

```
perform(anon)
```

The problem is `anon` and `perform` take a type parameter `T` and at no point are you declaring what `T` is.  The compiler can only infer type parameters in a function call from passed arguments, not from within the function body, so it cannot infer in `anon` that `T` should be `String`.

Notice that if you call

```
perform[String](Thing.data = _)
```

the compiler has no issue because it now knows what `T` should be, and if you try to use any type besides string, you'll get a type mismatch error, but the error occurs in the body of the anonymous function, not on the call to `perform`.

However, when you call

```
perform(Thing.data_=)
```

you are passing the method `Thing.data_=`, which is explicitly defined as `Box[String] => Unit`, so the compiler *can* infer `perform`'s type parameter because it is coming from a function argument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could a manifest make it so that the [String] is no longer required when using `perform(Thing.data = _)`?